# Append blank after point or comma

Tags: jquery, arrays, split, textarea

In a form , I have a textarea and I would like to use javascript to alter the value of it.
The constrains are :

- after every ',' or '.' i would like to add an empty space.
- if the '.' is between numbers ( like 2.3) it shouldn't add an empty space.

I've tried this code , but the browser gets blocked for a few seconds...

```
$('#edit-body').bind('input propertychange', function()
{
    var numbers = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"];
    var arr = $(this).val().split('');
    var news;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length ; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == "." || arr[i] == ",")
        {    

            if (numbers.indexOf(arr[i-1]) <0 && numbers.indexOf(arr[i+1]) < 0)
            {
                if (arr[i+1] != ' '){
                    arr.splice(i, 0, ' ');
                }
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(arr.toString());
    $(this).val(arr.toString());   
});
```

Please , help me out here...

Comment: your name is "Stack Overfolow"? :) nice :D

Comment: Hmmm... `.keyup()` might be a better way to do this, keeping track of only the last two characters typed and then inserting the space if the last typed character is not in the set of `digits`. Let me see if I can put together a fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/eUEve/3/)

```
var prevCode = 0;
$('#testing').keypress(function (e) {
    $('#kC').val(e.keyCode);
    $('#pC').val(prevCode);
    if ((prevCode == 44 || prevCode == 46) && (e.keyCode < 49 || e.keyCode > 57)) {
        var txtCurr = $('#testing').val();
        var lenCurr = txtCurr.length;
        var txtNew = txtCurr.substr(0,lenCurr);
        $('#testing').val(txtNew + " ");
    }
    prevCode = e.keyCode;
});
```

Comment: thanks for the example , but as i can see if there are more than 3 letters typed then it doesn't work properly..

Comment: Not so. It works no matter how many characters are in the `textarea`, it just depends on how fast you type. It seems the code can't really keep up with a fast typist. Let me try using the `.keypress()` method.

Comment: you are right. but also if the text is copy-pasted into the textarea the keyup event isn't fired up...

Comment: EDITED - see if that works better for you. I did not consider copy/paste... that's a whole different issue. LOL